# removeFromSuperview can't reopen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, uiview

I have a button (Buy) to open up a UIView (viewInAppPurchases) on top of another UIView (viewMenu). The Buy button is in the UIView viewMenu. I also have a button (Close) in the UIView viewInAppPurchases.

In the code when clicking the close button in the viewInAppPurchases, it shall close the view and go back to the viewMenu. But when clicking on the Buy button again, nothing happens. It should reopen the viewInAppPurchases UIView.

What else should I add and/or change to the code so when the Buy button is clicked again, it shall open up the viewInAppPurchases again?

In Header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewInAppPurchases;
```

In implementation .m file:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClose: (UIButton*)sender
{
[_viewInAppPurchases removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Below is the IAP as GaryRiches request. I noticed that I didn't have a "close button" instruction in the IAP itself, but only through the MenuViewController.

How do I put the close button instructions in it?

BuyView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import "MyIAPHelper.h"

@interface BuyView : UIView
{
SKProduct *product;

NSMutableArray *lstProducts;
int productIndex;


BOOL hasProducts;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *parentViewController;
- (IBAction)buyCoin:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)shareTwitterGetCoin:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)shareFacebookGetCoin:(id)sender;

@end
```

BuyView.m

```
#import "BuyView.h"

@implementation BuyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
// Initialization code
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(productPurchased:)
name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}
return self;
}
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
//        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
UIView *mainView = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
//Just in case the size is different (you may or may not want this)
mainView.frame = self.bounds;

[self addSubview:mainView];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(productPurchased:)
name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
}
return self;
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during
animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
}
*/


- (IBAction)buyCoin:(id)sender {
BUTTON_SOUND
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
NSString *productID = @"";
switch (btn.tag) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"buy 0.99");
        productIndex = 0;
        productID = FIRST_TIER;
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"buy 1.99");
        productIndex = 1;
        productID = SECOND_TIER;
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"buy 4.99");
        productIndex = 2;
        productID = THIRD_TIER;
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"buy 9.99");
        productIndex = 3;
        productID = FOURTH_TIER;
        break;
    case 4:
        NSLog(@"buy 19.99");
        productIndex = 4;
        productID = FIFTH_TIER;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
SKProduct *selectedProduct;
for (int i=0; i<lstProducts.count; i++) {
    SKProduct *_product = [lstProducts objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([_product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productID]) {
        selectedProduct = _product;
        break;
    }
}
[[MyIAPHelper shareInstance] buyProduct:selectedProduct];
}
- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"===========PurchaseViewController===========");
NSLog(@"purchased success");
//Add coin here IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification
int increaCoin = 0;

switch (productIndex) {
    case 0:
        increaCoin = 100;
        break;
    case 1:
        increaCoin = 250;
        break;
    case 2:
        increaCoin = 750;
        break;
    case 3:
        increaCoin = 2000;
        break;
    case 4:
        increaCoin = 5000;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

NSString *strMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have purchased
successfully and got %d coins",increaCoin];

UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:strMsg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];

[self updateCoinWithIncreaseCoin:increaCoin];
}
- (void)updateCoinWithIncreaseCoin:(int)increaseCoin_{

int currentCoin = [Utils getCoin];
[Utils updateCoin:(currentCoin + increaseCoin_)];
}
- (IBAction)shareTwitterGetCoin:(id)sender {
BUTTON_SOUND
NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![userdefaults objectForKey:@"FIRST_SHARE_TWITTER"]) {
    [userdefaults setObject:@"Abcd" forKey:@"FIRST_SHARE_TWITTER"];
    [userdefaults synchronize];

SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController
composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[controller setInitialText:@"Check out this new App!"];
[controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APP_URL]];
[self.parentViewController presentViewController:controller
animated:YES completion:^{
        //get coin here
        NSLog(@"get coin share twitter");
        int currentCoin = [Utils getCoin] + 30;
        [Utils updateCoin:currentCoin];
    }];
}

}

- (IBAction)shareFacebookGetCoin:(id)sender {
BUTTON_SOUND
NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![userdefaults objectForKey:@"FIRST_SHARE_FACEBOOK"]) {
    [userdefaults setObject:@"Abc" forKey:@"FIRST_SHARE_FACEBOOK"];
    [userdefaults synchronize];

SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [controller setInitialText:@"Check out this new App!"];
    [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APP_URL]];
    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
        //add coin here
        NSLog(@"get coin share facebook");
        int currentCoin = [Utils getCoin] + 30;
        [Utils updateCoin:currentCoin];
    }];
}else{

}

}
@end
```

Comment: Could you also show the code that displays the IAP view as that's the one that isn't working.

Comment: If you remove your file from the view, you have to add it back as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What else should I add and/or change to the code so when the Buy
>   button is clicked again, it shall open up the viewInAppPurchases
>   again?

You should add it back to the view from which you removed it.

You can do it on click event by:

```
[self.view addSubview: _viewInAppPurchases];
```

Also, have you consider hiding it instead of removing it completly and then adding it back?

To hide your view:

```
[_viewInAppPurchases setHidden:YES];
```

To show it again:

```
[_viewInAppPurchases setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Yes, I've consider of hiding it, too. I don't know how to do it as I am very new to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the

```
removeFromSuperview
```

to

```
setHidden:Yes
```

and it did the trick.